# Como ler arquivo .txt e passar para uma string com JS puro

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar um código que leia arquivos .txt de forma local a principio, e o texto de cada arquivo seja atribuido a uma strings, para usar serem reproduzidos em uma página

Sou iniciante ainda então pesquisei alguns códigos que tentassem ler os arquivos somente com JS puro e consegui esses dois:

```
fetch('/teste/arquivo1.txt')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
})

getText("/teste/arquivo1.txt");
    var myObject;
    var myText;
    async function getText(file) {
      myObject = await fetch(file);
      myText = await myObject.text();
    }
```

Mas não consigo passar para uma string de fora dessas funções assim:

```
var texto = "";

fetch('/teste/arquivo1.txt')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
  texto = text;
})
console.log(texto)
```

Comment: Não é que não consegue passar a variável pra fora, ela já está fora. O problema é que do jeito que fez, o console log vai ocorrer antes de dar tempo do texto chegar. muito mais simples é você usar o texto dentro do 2º then e lá mesmo colocar o código que exibe onde ele deve aparecer

Comment: Consegui fiz mais ou menos desse jeito e interagindo com um botão muito obrigado, só tenho que tentar acertar agora escrita do texto do .txt no paragrafo ja não ta reconhecendo quebra de linha mesmo usando o split e array, o maximo que eu consigo é substituir a quebra de linha por virgula

Answer (score -3):

```
let texto = "";

const myRequest = new Request('/teste/arquivo1.txt');

fetch(myRequest)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then((text) => {
    texto = text;
  });
console.log(texto)
```